# Asus XTion Pro Live on embedded Linux using OpenNI2?

Tags: ros, openni2, xtion, asus, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm going to use Asus XTion Pro Live (0601) on my robot running ROS Indigo on a NVidia Jetson TK1, but I have problems receiving data from the sensor.
I installed openni2_launch and run it, the sensor is correctly recognized, but no data messages (both RGB and 3D) are generated. I tried it on both USB 2.0 and USB3.0 ports, on the first it is not detected, on the second it is detected, but it does not send data.

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195565/asus-xtion-pro-live-on-embedded-linux-using-openni2?/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2014-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I usually find it worthwhile to compile OpenNI2 myself. For some reason I seem to be experiencing problems using the precompiled versions. It could be worth a shot at least..

Also it is worth a shot to try the samples of OpenNI2. In case you don't have a graphical interface, I believe SimpleRead doesn't open a window and just outputs some data from the camera. Then you know at least that it is connected and functional.

ps. I am running OpenNI2 with the Xtion on an Odroid U2 so I am pretty sure it should work on the Jetson TK1.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-22**:
If you have trouble with the precompiled OpenNI2 binaries, PLEASE  let me know. If you're having trouble, someone else probably is as well, and I can't fix things if I don't know that they're broken.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-10-22**:
Just to clarify, these are the OpenNI2 libraries, not the openni2 package from ROS. In addition, it was a long time ago, but I believe I had the same problem as @Myzhar, it just wouldn't find the Xtion.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-22**:
I tune and build a significant number of the dependencies for the ARM builds by hand, including OpenNI and OpenNI2.

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2014-10-23**:
I tried only the version of OpenNI2 coming from the repository together with openni2_lauch.

Now I would like to remove this OpenNI2 version and to compile it by myself, but I do not know two things:

1. how to remove the package and its dependencies
2. how to for ROS to use my OpenNI2
   Any reference?

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2014-10-23**:
I think that before recompiling I will try the precompiled version of OpenNI2 from http://structure.io/openni.
My problem remains the same... see (1) and (2) from my last comment ;-)

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2014-10-23**:
@ahendrix I downloaded OpenNI2 source code from git and compiled it following this guide:
http://jetsonhacks.com/2014/08/28/occipital-structure-sensor/
I tried "SimpleRead" example, but I cannot find the sensor.
So I tried running "rqt" and I can see RGB and Depth, but not the msg pointcloud2

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-10-24**:
@ahendrix, next time I run into this issue I will post something to let you know